# AQuery - use cache when offline?

Tags: android, caching, android-query, aquery

I'm using AQuery and referencing with this page: https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI

Is there a way that when the device is offline, an ajax call can use the cached data, but still let that expire when the device gets back online? Through some testing it seems that once the cached data expires, it just goes away, but I want it to pull from that cache when the device is offline.

Comment: I've noticed that it automatically uses the cache data when the device is offline, but I don't know if the cache expires after a time limit or based on device resources or both. I need it to be permanent as well. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Sort of.I started storing the results in an SQLite database, and if I found the device was offline I would pull the latest and run that through the same callback process.